# Problema en un programa en C

Tags: c, dev-c++

En el siguiente código intente hacer un programa que solicite una cantidad de números, donde se busca la cantidad de los números que se introduzcan, el promedio de los pares y impares, y la cantidad de pares e impares. El problema es el siguiente, al ejecutarlo, la cantidad no se esta contado, sino sumando o multiplicando, y la cantidad de impares da como resultado un número mayor del que coloco. He revisado pero no encuentro el fallo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
    int x;
    int contador,cantidadI,cantidadP;
    float prom;

while (x>0){
    printf("\n Ingrese un numero:");
    fflush( stdin );
    scanf("%i",&x);
    contador++;
    if(x%2==0){
        fflush( stdin );
        cantidadP++;
    }
    else {
        fflush( stdin );
        cantidadI++;
    }
}
prom=(cantidadP+cantidadI)/contador;

printf("\nLa cantidad de numeros introducidos es de:%i",contador);
printf("\nEl promedio es de:%f",prom);
printf("\nLa cantidad de numeros pares es de:%i",cantidadP);
printf("\nLa cantidad de numeros impares es de:%i",cantidadI);
getch();

return 0;
```

Comment: No has inicializado las variables y contadores. por lo que estos parten con un valor aleatorio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al parecer no estás inicializando las variables incluso el contador lo estás solo declarando sin darle ningún valor por lo tanto estos tomaran un dato/valor basura y no inicializara desde donde tú quieres, recomiendo que todo lo que sea contador o que vaya a contener un número lo inicialices dependiendo de tus necesidades. Buena suerte colega

Answer (score 1):

Al realizar un variable como contador la tienes que inicializar si no tiene un valor aleatorio